# Float: left and Float: right with min-width

Tags: html, css

Using `min-width: 156px;` in a div that contains two divs, one `float: left` and the other `float: right`, min-width becomes 100%. How to fix?

Comment: Fist of all make sure min-width how works. First try it your self.

Comment: If total width of your child divs become grater than the 156px, then its take width as 100%. Please check div with of your child divs.

Comment: @user2579059: could you add some more detail? It’s not clear what your actual problem is. An example of the problem on jsfiddle.net would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure you understand what `min-width` does. It sets a minimum width for an element, e.g. “this `<div>` must be as least 156px wide, but may be more”.

By default,`<div>`s will expand to take up all available space, so just declaring `min-width: 156px`on a `<div>` probably wouldn’t affect it.

And `min-width:156px` seems to work (in Chrome, at least) when applied to a `<div>` with a left float and a right float inside it. See:

- http://jsfiddle.net/b8jY5/1/

The grandparent `<div>` has `width: 50px`, but the parent `<div>` with `min-width:156px` is still 156 pixels wide.

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements have `100%` width by default. I think you must use either width or `max-width` if you want to adjust its width, not `min-width`.

Comment: DIVs actually *don't* have a default width of 100%. They have a default width of `auto`, which is quite different. (Adding margin/padding subtracts from the effective 100%, whereas if you set width to 100% without changing the box model the margin/padding will add to the effective 100%.)

Answer (score -1):

I dont why you are doing like this. But you can solve it by giving `display: inline-block;` for the outer `div`.

Comment: Eh? Could you provide a JS fiddle (jsfiddle.net) to explain what you mean?

Comment: that sentence doesn‘t make any sense either.